# Ask about TSMADUMP Batch utility for SSL configuration

Tags: mail-server, hmail-server

My domain name is in https://example.com so while testing in TSMADUmp batch utility I got an error is:

Fetchcing domains from URL [https://webmail.example.com/Services/svcDomainAdmin.asmx]
Error:System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
at TSMADump.SvcDomainAdmin.svcDomainAdmin.GetAllDomains(String AuthUserName, String AuthPassword)
at TSMADump.Program.DomainAdminCommand.function(String[] args)
at TSMADump.Program.Command.execute(String[] args)

What can be done??

I am not getting where I need to change if anyone have details let me know.